# Logic Gates and De Morgan's law for "$a \text{ AND } b$"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I prove that $(a \text{ NAND } b) \text{ NAND } (a \text{ NAND } b ) \equiv a \text{ AND } b $?

So far I came up with a truth table for all the possibility combinations for the left side of the equation and the right side of the equation. I can see that if the a's and b's were all the same on the left side then I could prove the right side, but I don't know what happens when one of the a's or b's on the left side is different, what happens to the right side?

How can I use De Morgan's law to prove this or any other methods? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "one of the a's?"  The value of $a$ has to be the same everywhere.  I can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: The easiest way to prove this is to negate both sides, I think.

Comment: I don't understand your problem with truth tables. Please, could you explain it better?

Comment: Your truth-table should have shown that these sentences have the exact same truth-conditions, and thus are equivalent. Maybe you did something wrong in working out the truth-table? Can you show us your truth-table?

Answer (score 2):

Using De Morgan's law ($\,\overline{xy}\equiv \overline x+\overline y$), we have
$$
\overline{\overline{ab}\cdot\overline{ab}} \equiv \overline{\overline{ab}}+\overline{\overline{ab}} \equiv ab.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your truth table needs to show the third and last columns are the same (true when true and false when false):  $$\def\nand{\operatorname{N\!A\!N\!D}}\def\true{\mathrm{T}}\def\false{\mathrm{F}}\boxed{\begin{array}{c:c|c:c|l}a & b & a\land b & a\nand b &(a\nand b)\nand(a\nand b)\\ \hline \true & \true & && \\ \hdashline \true & \false & && \\ \hdashline\false & \true & && \\ \hdashline\false& \false &&& \\ \hline && \uparrow && \uparrow\end{array}}$$

Why doesn't yours?

Answer (score 1):

We can use $\uparrow$ to represent "NAND":

Assume that $x \in \big((a \uparrow b) \uparrow (a \uparrow b)\big) \iff x \in \bigg(\neg\big(\neg(a \wedge b) \wedge \neg(a \wedge b)\big)\bigg)$

Using De Morgan's law:

$\hspace{66.5 mm} \iff x \in \Bigg(\neg\bigg(\neg\big((a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge b)\big)\bigg)\Bigg)$

$\hspace{66.5 mm} \iff x \in \Big(\big((a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge b)\big)\Big)$

$\hspace{66.5 mm} \iff x \in \big(a \wedge b\big) \hspace{5 mm}$ (Q.E.D.)